How can you put a repeating pattern into a seamless tile?
I'm having huge problems with a kaleidoscope repeating pattern i made in an app to get it to go into a seamless tile. I tried to upload the picture to show what I mean but was unable to. But basically it's a square based repeat pattern but no matter how much I try to judge by eye where to crop it the pattern ends up with slightly choppy lines or missing bits when enlarged as a seamless pattern. I know that if there was a way to judge intellengtly enough to where exactly to crop it could be done as its square based and repeating but how I can do this? Can it be done in photoshop or with some AI tool? I really want to make it into a seamless tile for POD so would be really grateful for advice.

Hard to give advise without seeing the pattern you're referring to.  It might be possible to fix in Photoshop but we cannot give advice on how to fix the issue if we cannot see what the issue is.

Have you tried searching? https://duckduckgo.com/?q=create+seamless+pattern+from+image

Thanks, that looks like a useful link,  I'll have a browse!

If you have access to Photoshop, I recommend using its built-in pattern preview. If you discover issues with your pattern, you can easily correct them using your preferred Photoshop techniques. Any changes made at the edge of the pattern will automatically wrap to the opposite edge.

I didn't know about the pattern preview, that should make things a bit easier, thanks!
